# Can we get to know what was the time of the last screenshot or photo taken by the user

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, django, angularjs

I am working on a website in Django.
I want to get to know the last image the user has taken and is saved in its phone that means that photo shouldn't be sent by anyone, it should be taken by the user's device especially screenshot.
I have searched a lot of ways but not able to find the real.
Is there any method that will work on website as, I am not sure, but I fear that  the web-browser don't allow this.
For Example, if a user takes a screenshot it will be going to save in his phone in a particular folder named **Screenshots**. So, I wanted to know what is the times at what the last picture in his Screenshot folder is taken. Can I do this.

Please help me out

Comment: taken? I assume you mean willingly uploaded?

Comment: This is not possible

Comment: don't mix jquery and react friend

Comment: Please read carefully through your question again. Try to rephrase it, it's not clear what you want to achive

Answer (score 0):

You could check EXIF tags for the image, there should be a tag *DateTimeOriginal*. Please note, EXIF tags may or may not be available in the uploaded image. If EXIF metadata is not available, you will not be able to get the the image creation date. Full list of tags could be found [here](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/EXIF.html)